# Sending and sharing an image

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to follow the steps on the [AndroidQuery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidquery&hl=en) app on "Share and send image"

[image]
I have followed the code attentively and have made sure everything is exactly the same as it is on there, but I am getting errors.

I am getting an error on "aq" stating "aq cannot be resolved" and on "SEND_REQUEST" stating "SEND_REQUEST cannot be resolved to a variable"

Would someone be able to help me out with this, I'm not sure why I am getting these errors.

```
  case R.id.ShareWallpaper:



        String url = "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02370/12C_Spider_4_2370457b.jpg";
        File file = aq.makeSharedFile(url, "car.png");

        if(file != null) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("Image/jpeg");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"), SEND_REQUEST);

        }


        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, they obviously haven't shown all the code on the example

Comment: @kalyanpvs You cannot copy and paste from an app, I wrote the code from the app and try to understand it as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Share image the use this:

```
        Bitmap bm;

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) yourimageview.getDrawable();
        bm = drawable.getBitmap();
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("image/jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
```

SEND_REQUEST is a Integer Variable so you have to declared it as a globally like:

```
  public final static int SEND_REQUEST =0;
```